# Revoke all access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Good Day,
Current environment: Azure AD and on-premises AD. Both in sync.

Is there a script that can run against a specific user to find all roles and groups assigned to that user and then revoke access/remove all these roles and memberships?

Note this user is a global admin and so want to revoke access as quickly as possible

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome, if you have a problem, please provide us with a [mcve]. If you are unsure, take a peek at [ask]

Comment: remove the global admin role then delete the user directly?

Comment: thanks, its better to disable first, keep for a month or two then delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the PowerShell module AzureAD you can build your script:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0

This is an example of all available commands in the AzureAD Module
[image: Rrmove-AzureAD*]

You can install the module from you Powershell with the following commands:

```
Install-Module AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
```

Hope this helps!